Problemas con la libreria python-crontab
En esta ocasión vengo solicitando ayuda porque estoy trabajando con una serie de tareas que necesito se ejecuten en segundo plano cada cierto tiempo y que mejor manera de combinar nuestros scripts python con cron.
He instalado la libreria python-crontab con pip y he escrito las siguientes lineas a modo de prueba de concepto para entender como usar esta librería:
from crontab import CronTab
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess as sub

ARCHIVO_DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).absolute()

usuario = sub.run(["whoami"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.split("\n")[0]

cron_wallpaper = CronTab(user=usuario)

job = cron_wallpaper.new(command=f"/usr/bin/python {ARCHIVO_DIR_PATH}/wallpaper_conteo.py", comment="wallpaper")
job.minute.every(1)

cron_wallpaper.write()

Lo que verán es un programa sencillo para configurar y programar una tarea de un fondo de pantalla dinámico cada cierto tiempo. Este script funciona en terminal por lo que su funcionalidad está comprobada. El problema que tengo es que no hace nada, asumo y sospecho que el tema es de cron y que me falta "ver" algo que aun no estoy viendo pero ¿qué puede ser? Agradecería cualquier comentario, sugerencia, regaño :P o algo que me de una pista de saber la razón de porque no sucede nada.
Saludos a todos y excelente día.
NOTA COMPLEMENTARIA:
Me he dado cuenta que al realizar mis pruebas el problema viene desde el archivo de cron creado con el comando crontab -u username -e, aquí lo que hago es agregar los elementos que componen a la instrucción cron de la siguiente manera:









PATH="las rutas que derivan del comando echo $PATH"; ruta/completa/de/python ruta/absoluta/de/mi/script.py









Si observamos con cuidado pensaríamos que dado este comando se ejecutaría la tarea cron pero no es así, no pasa nada. Por eso escribo esta entrada ya que no sé porque no puedo correr mi script con cierta periodicidad en segundo plano con cron. Cualquier aporte es mas que bienvenido. Gracias por tu tiempo amig@.

Desconozco esa libreria de python.. pero para que un cron se ejecute, la aplicacion que lo lanza y controla debe estar viva todo el tiempo... ese codigo no parece hacer eso... para hacer un cron, nada mejor que el sistema operativo...

¿Por qué no editar crontab directamente? Eso facilita la administración del sistema (tienes todas las tareas definidas en un solo lugar) Recuerda que cada usuario puede tener su propio crontab.

hola @CandidMoe, porque es para una aplicación que será de dominio público por eso no podemos hacerlo manualmente. saludos.

El problema es que ARCHIVO_DIR_PATH incluye el nombre del programa que modifica el crontab. Si a eso le concatenas el nombre del archivo que quieres ejecutar, queda algo incorrecto.
Digamos que el código que muestras se llama "prog.py". Entonces, ARCHIVO_DIR_PATH queda en
/home/usario/algun_directorio/prog.py

y el programa que estas pasando a contrab sería
/home/usario/algun_directorio/prog.py/wallpaper_conteo.py

que obviamente no existe.
Solución
Una solución es usar os.cwd() para obtener el directorio actual.
from crontab import CronTab
import os
import subprocess as sub

ARCHIVO_DIR_PATH = os.getcwd()

usuario = sub.run(["whoami"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.split("\n")[0]

cron_wallpaper = CronTab(user=usuario)

job = cron_wallpaper.new(command=f"/usr/bin/python {ARCHIVO_DIR_PATH}/wallpaper_conteo.py", comment="wallpaper")
job.minute.every(1)

cron_wallpaper.write()

Puede ser que el directorio actual no sea el correcto y debas buscar otro método para obtener el directorio.
Para revisar que funcione, usa crontab -l para revisar como quedó finalmente el crontab.

duda tecnica.. en cualquier otro lenguaje ese programa se muere pq no esta en loop.. aca en python no pasa eso???

@gbianchi El programa simplemente modifica el crontab del usuario, evitandole tener que hacerlo a mano. Una vez modificado, el SO se encarga de la ejecución de las tareas.

ahhh listo.. solo funciona en linux, es para modificar el SO.. genial..

@gbianchi Windows tiene "scheduled tasks". El programa del OP podría extenderse para funcionar en cualquier de ambos S.O.

Hola @gbianchi, complementando un poco mas la respuesta. Algo interesante que tiene la librería de python-crontab es que puedes modificar el archivo crontab y eliminar las tareas programadas desde un script de python evitando hacer esta tarea de forma manual en el archivo de crontab precisamente y que es de gran ayuda para aplicaciones automatizadas.

Y tambien es una gran forma de insertar algun tipo de programa malicioso.. que interesante...

@gbianchi Es el crontab del usuario, no del sistema. Las tareas se ejecutaban bajo la cuenta personal.

no deja de ser una idea hermosa jajajaj
